# Image not loading in firefox(dynamic image tag generation)

Tags: php

I am trying to load image dynamically using DirectoryIterator. The problem is that the images are getting loaded as expected in google chrome and IE, but in firefox nothing shows up.

Below is the code that I am working on.

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator(getcwd()."\emoticons");  
foreach($dir as $folder)
{
  if(strlen($folder) > 2)  // sometimes $folder is blank so.
  {

  $files = new DirectoryIterator(getcwd()."\emoticons\\".$folder);

  echo "<br>".$folder;
  foreach($files as $file)
  {
    echo "<img src = 'emoticons\\".$folder."\\".$file."'></img>"; // doesnt work in FF.
  }

  }
}
```

I dont know why this could possibly be happening. If anyone has any experience around this problem then please share.

Regards,
   Sameeksha.

Comment: Please note that `\ ` is a notation that is _not_ valid on the internet. It is inly used inside the MS-Windows world. All other systems (so also the internet) use a standard folder separator: `/`. Oh, and: the content of the `src` attribute inside the `img` tag  must be encosed in quotes, typically double quotes (src=`"..."`).

Comment: Always when trying to debug something that "does not work" inside a browser: you need to ask the browser what the problem is, not us. Open the development console inside the browser (install the FireBug extension in FF for this) and see what error the browser itself throws upon this. Then you have your answer.

Comment: @arkascha... I dont see an error here in the console.

Comment: Sorry, I doubt this. But ok, if the browser does _not_ choke out an error about this strange code, then you have to check the servers log file instead, since then the browser should try do load _something_.

Comment: @arkascha.. the '/' is working. I tried this before, but that was not working because of some other reason so didnt try it again. Now its working. Thanks.

Comment: Tag img has not the closure tag. It must be <img src="" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please replace '\' by '/'

Here is the new code:

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator(getcwd()."/emoticons");  
foreach($dir as $folder)
{
  if(strlen($folder) > 2)  // sometimes $folder is blank so.
  {

  $files = new DirectoryIterator(getcwd()."/emoticons/".$folder);

  echo "<br>".$folder;
  foreach($files as $file)
  {
    echo "<img src = 'emoticons/".$folder."/".$file."'></img>"; // doesnt work in FF.
  }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you got adBlock in your FF ? Sometime adBlock auto hide banner.

Or you can use Firebug plugin to check the image path.

Comment: @arkascha : ironic comments don't help. I have seen adBlock playing nasty tricks so I give +1 to this answer.

Comment: what's "ironic" about his comment?